# How to define variable in .emacs file?

Tags: emacs

It is my .emacs file:

```
(setq load-path (cons  "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B02/lib/erlang/lib/tools-2.6.12/emacs"
      load-path))
      (setq erlang-root-dir "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B")
      (setq exec-path (cons "/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B/bin" exec-path))
      (require 'erlang-start)
```

As you can see the erlang paths are not very consistent.

I want to define a variable to capture the path `/usr/local/Cellar/erlang/R16B02` so I can set the path in one place and use the variable to construct the relevant erlang paths.

What is the syntax for doing that? I think I will need to know how to declare the variable as well as the concatenation of the variable and path suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (setq erpath "/usr/path/to/erlang")

and then use it like this

> (setq erlang-root-dir (format "%s/%s" erpath "R16B"))